# Why is otherwise defined as True in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I just found out about guarded equations in Haskell, here's an example:

```
abs n | n >= 0 = n
      | otherwise = -n
```

it basically says that function `abs` returns `n` if `n >= 0`, otherwise it returns `-n`.

In the book it says that the the standard prelude otherwise is defined like this: `otherwise = True`, why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *reason* why `otherwise` exists - and why it is defined the way it is - is purely for stylistic purposes. The example you gave could be just as validly, writtent like so:

```
abs n | n >= 0 = n
      | True = -n
```

But `otherwise` just reads more nicely. In particular it reads like a mathematical definition.

Answer (score 5):

It's a cute hack so that you can write definitions like the one you quote:

```
abs n | n >= 0 = n
      | otherwise = -n
```

Which looks fairly straightforwardly (if you're familiar with mathematical notation conventions) like it says "`abs n`, if n is greater or equal to zero, is equal to `n`, and otherwise is equal to `-n`".

But the simple guard syntax is *always* the guard symbol `|`, followed by a condition, followed by the `=` symbol, followed by the resulting expression. There isn't actually any way in that syntax to express an "else"/"otherwise" case that applies with no condition of its own, if all of the other conditions failed.

Somebody early on noticed that the guard syntax provides a way of getting the *effect* of an "otherwise" case. Since the guard conditions are checked in order, top-down, you can simply give the last one a condition of `True`. That will always match, but since you wrote it last it will only be checked if all the other conditions failed. That would give you:

```
abs n | n >= 0 = n
      | True = -n
```

But the simple appearance of `True` doesn't immediately communicate the idea of "else" or "otherwise". So someone had the bright idea of putting a standard definition in the prelude:

```
otherwise :: Bool
otherwise = True
```

Now we can write:

```
abs n | n >= 0 = n
      | otherwise = -n
```

And we've visually got the idea of an "else" case in our guards, without changing the compiler to implement more complex syntax! Brilliant!

TBH I'm not sure if the language were being defined today that we would have done this. It's a bit weird that `otherwise` is sort of a semi-reserved name now. In your own code you might have bindings for when some external conditions are met, and need a catch all binding for when none of the conditions are met. If you accidentally call that `otherwise` you might get warnings about shadowing, or strange errors if you happen to try to use the `| otherwise = ...` idiom within the scope of your `otherwise` binding (or worst of all if your `otherwise` is actually of type `Bool` and is `False`, you might be tearing your hair out trying to figure out why your `| otherwise` guard isn't firing). And we haven't even really gained the ability to have this nice syntactic extra without modifying the compiler, because the compiler has to know to treat `otherwise` a bit specially in its exhaustiveness checking! (Or maybe it doesn't and it relies on ordinary inlining to recognise the catch-all `True` condition... the rest of my point still stands though)

**TLDR:** you can treat `| otherwise` like it's special syntax for a "guard without a condition". That concept is actually *implemented* by simply having `otherwise` be a Prelude definition for `True`, but you mostly should ignore that (it's not intended for you to actually *use* `otherwise` in boolean expressions in any other context).

Comment: Agree, it's a bit of a silly solution. I wonder if it would have caused any parsing trouble to just allow omitting a condition entirely. That would be reasonable enough, since it is already allowed to write more than one, comma-separated, which are and-ed together – so empty condition naturally corresponds to constant `True`. And it would still be very clear to read.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think comma separated conditions came in with pattern guards, since you can't compose those with `&&` (or any normal operator). Otherwise yeah, really weird to have put in dedicated syntax for writing `,` instead of `&&`, but not for an `else` on guards!

Answer (score 3):

It is defined as `True`, because the `otherwise` case always has to succeed.

For example, we can write:

```
signum n | n < 0 = -1
         | n == 0 = 0
         | otherwise = 1
```

and in this case Haskell checks if `n < 0` is `True`, then, if it is `False` it checks if `n == 0` is `True`, and then if it is `False` it checks if `otherwise` is `True`. As you can see, it has to go case by case until it finds one that is `True`, this is why otherwise has to be True (in order to succeed, when everything else is `False`).